# Uneven margins memoir class

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

I'm having trouble with the margins of my report. The report is set up with memoir class:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,dvipsnames,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

What could cause the margins to be scewed (not be mirrors on left and right pages), when they're supposed to be fixed to the same values in both sides?

[image]

Comment: Twoside, the default, will flip the left and right margin on odd and even pages this is normal

Comment: Yes, but why are the margins not symmetrical?

Comment: You are setting left margin to 3.5cm and right margin to 2.5cm. So why are you expecting them to be symmetric?

Comment: Symmetric in the sense that the left page would have margins that mirrored the margins on the right page.

Comment: As I said left and right margins gets flipped on odd/even pages undrrctwoside setup.

Comment: Then why is this not what the picture shows? The grey line down the middle is the cut between the pages.

Comment: It is exactly what the image shows. Remember you are always designing an odd page (because we start on page 1). So the page on the left is an even page which have the smaller width on the outside and the larger on the inside which is exactly the flipped on the margins for the odd page, the page you designed, which has the inner margin being the larger. If you look as it as inner/spine and outer margins the design is always the same. But when you look at it as left and right the margins are flipped.

Comment: Your posted result looks odd to me. The left hand page (no. 20) has a narrow outer margin and a wider inner margin while the right hand page (no. 21) appears to have equal inner and outer margins. This should not happen. Could you provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that shows the problem (use the `lipsum` package for text).

Comment: I tried removing the code bit by bit. The problem disappeared when removing the front page. I don't know how to post it here though.

Comment: @np874 In my case the asymmetry was caused by a `\setlength{\rightskip}{10mm}` line, which I left in the code accidentally. (Although that affected only the text, and not the headers, etc.)